# Cloud Composer is not getting deleted

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-composer

Cloud Composer is not getting deleted properly with this error:

> DELETE operation on this environment failed 4 days ago with the following error message:
>   RPC Skipped due to required preoperation not finished yet.
>
> RPC Skipped due to required preoperation not finished yet.

here's the error screenshot:
[image: Error Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, follow the below steps to delete environments resources manually:

1. Delete GKE cluster, that corresponds to environment
2. Delete the Google Storage bucket used by environment
3. Delete the related [deployments](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/deployments/deleting-deployments) with:

`gcloud deployment-manager deployments delete <DEPLOYMENT_NAME> --delete-policy=ABANDON`

4. Then try again to delete the Composer environments with:

`gcloud composer environments delete <ENVIRONMENT_NAME> --location <LOCATION>`

The problem you are facing could be also related with a misconfiguration with the Cloud Composer service account in your project. By default, Cloud Composer environments run as the Compute Engine default service account, but when you are using a custom service account, at a minimum, that service account requires the permissions that the `composer.worker` [role](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam) provides to access resources in the Cloud Composer environment. Please refer to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts) for further details about how to grant a role to a service account.

Please, try to add the [policy binding](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/add-iam-policy-binding) for Cloud Composer API Service Agent role to the service account, so the command would be:

`gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <PROJECT_ID> --member=<MEMBER>  --role=roles/composer.serviceAgent`

The `member` should be of the form `user|group|serviceAccount:email` or `domain:domain` (refer to documentation).

Then, please retry the action of remove your Composer environments. I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.